# OpenCart - Cannot pass data between MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller, opencart2.x

I'm trying to pass some data from database though product controller and finally on product view.
The problem is that i tried many different situations but nothing worked.
In a few words, i want to retrieve the customer's zone id from oc_address table into product page on variable $zone.

**catalog\model\catalog\product.php (Model)**

```
public function getZoneFromCustomer()
{
 $zone = array();
 $this->db->query("SELECT zone_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "address WHERE address_id = '". (int)$this->customer->getAddressId() ."'");
     
foreach ($query->rows as $result) {
        $zone = $result['zone_id'];
}

return $zone;
}
```

**catalog\controller\product\product.php (Controller)**

```
$data['zone'] = $this->model_catalog_product->getZoneFromCustomer();
```

**catalog\view\theme\default\template\product\product.tpl (View)**

```
if(isset($zone))
{
   echo $zone; 
}
```

OpenCart Version: 2.0.3.1

```
Notice: Undefined variable: zone in ...
```

Comment: Typo? `$this->db-query` vs `$this->db->query`

Comment: And shouldn't `getZoneFromCustomer()` return something?

Comment: yes sorry it's a typo. i also tried as  return $this->db->query("SELECT zone_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "address WHERE address_id = '6'"); but nothing changed

Comment: Can you add `$this->log->write(json_encode($query->rows));` above the `foreach` loop and check the logs after calling it?

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution. Opencart keeps a copy of modified files into a folder named "modification" into system folder and overrides the default code. If you delete those files from there then reverts to normal.

Comment: You shouldn't just delete the files, instead you should "refresh" the modification cache from the admin area, you may be deleting mods that break functionality